# Endospores contact with surfaces

Tags: microbiology, proteins, bacteriology, cell-culture

I am currently studying endospores-forming bacteria. To be specific B.subtilis. I noticed that the formed spores have strong contact "grip" with the surface it is forming on. For example, when they are formed on an agar plate you have to scrape them off it. where is this attachment coming from? is this some type of enzyme or protein? or is it something else?